# Is the time object created by the DateTime class affected by local time of the user's machine?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a timestamp column in some table in the database to keep track of the time of the insertions, and it's SQL is like

```
reg_date TIMESTAMP
```

so when I insert some data to the table it gets the time and put it there in the column reg_date

say I inserted a reset password request id to the table, and in the reset page I check for the difference in time between the time in the table and the time in which the user is using the id to reset the password

so, the question is: If the user's local time is behind or after that of the server will this affect the difference in time or the current time is generated by the server when using DateTime class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Client's machine time will affect your serverside data only if you send it directly via GET\POST requests and then pass as a parameter for DateTime object. 
Otherwise php script gets date, time and timezone from the server where it runs.

Most of the webservers are setup to UTC timezone (which is also a good practice for storing datetime records in DB), but I would recommend to check if that it is true for yours.

```
<?php

// This var contains only server time
$serverDataTime = new \DateTime();

try {
    $userTimeZone = new \DateTimeZone($_POST['timezone_from_client']);
    // this one depends on what was received from the client
    $userDateTime = new \DateTime( $_POST['date_time_from_client'], $userTimeZone );
} catch ( Exception $e ) {
    // wrong input
}
```

Manual: [PHP DateTime](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.construct.php)

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not.

PHP have no idea about client (computer) time, DateTime is affected only by server time.

Comment: Not server time, but server timezone or mysql level timezone setting.

Comment: @Shadow - that's not true. For me (date)time = time + timezone settings. But you are telling that php only uses server timezone settings and that it is ignoring server time. Where did php get the "right" time if not from server?

Comment: @Shadow - and if you override timezone settings in your php code, you are only using server time (without server timezone).

Comment: You might actually want to add that there are two servers involved. The webserver might not be using the same datetime settings as the database server.

Comment: I have no clue what you are talking about. When you retrieve a timestamp data from mysql, then the server time has no impact on that, only the timezone settings.

Comment: @SalmanA - you are right. I was just answering his php question (related to DateTime).

Comment: @Shadow - he is storing timestamp in database, but he is generating current timestamp with php DateTime.